# Jenkins - JIRA Plugin Issue

Tags: jenkins

I am a beginner to Jenkins and trying to configure one .NET project in Jenkins.

I have installed JIRA plugin and trying to configure the Plugin.

But when I enter the JIRA URL with proper username and password, I get an error when I click validate settings button:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSite$DescriptorImpl.doValidate(JiraSite.java:652)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at
```

Waiting for quick reply please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the best place to search for resolutions to Jenkins error messages is to search on the [Jenkins bug tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/).

You've encountered a bug in the latest Jira plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18268. Downgrade to Jira plugin 1.35 and you should be able to proceed. I don't know the details of your installation, but you can either downgrade the plugin to a previous version via the web interface, or [download the plugin manually](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/jira/) and replace the jira.hpi file.